# Next page can't be found if input on previous page was filled

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

I'm making a form on Wordpress website. My problem is easiest shown in practice: try submitting empty form (first one, black) on http://newzapchasti.evella.ru/ and it will redirect to the next page. Then try filling out the last input field of this form and submit it again. The same page (http://newzapchasti.evella.ru/quest.html) isn't found this time. 
My code is very simple:

```
<form action="/quest.html" method="post">
   <input name="year" type="text">
   <button type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing input field **name** attribute to other values, some names could make existing page display as 404.

Answer (score 1):

On the second page the form action is

```
<form action="http://newzapchasti.evella.ru/" method="post">
```

While on the first one is

```
<form action="/quest.html" method="post">
```

That may be the reason :)

Comment: nope, because same problem lingers if I delete second form entirely.

Comment: What I see after submitting the first form is this - http://pixbg.com/images/3be2cadc2930c28f63a2.png

Comment: do you mean first form? even if you do not fill in any input fields?

Comment: exactly. I enter the site, press the button and that is the result.

Comment: I figured it out. there were two issues here: 1. name 'year' wasn't suitable for my input name, other random names made that 404 page go away. 2. but only I could see it, because it wasn't published (I'm very new to Wordpress):-) So you actually helped.

Comment: I am glad I helped after all :)